# Difference between freeMemory() and totalMemory()

Tags: java

What's the difference between `freeMemory()` and `totalMemory()`? Both are the total amount of memory currently available for JVM.

```
    /**
     *
     * @return  an approximation to the total amount of memory currently
     *          available for future allocated objects, measured in bytes.
     */
    public native long freeMemory();

    /**
     *
     * @return  the total amount of memory currently available for current
     *          and future objects, measured in bytes.
     */
    public native long totalMemory();
```

Comment: It's about "future" vs "current and future"

Comment: FreeStaturdayTime() - number of hours available (not yet planned!) to do stuff this Saturday, TotalSaturdayTime() - number of hours you'll be awake this Saturday (no staying up later than already decided by your significant other / cat!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`freeMemory()` says `for future`, and `totalMemory()` says `for current and future`.

Literally, `freeMemory()` tells the memory for new allocating objects and `totalMemory()` tells the total memory (memory already allocated + free memory)